# Canonical Questions and Answers

Tags: discussion

I am interested in writing a few question and answers to provide some general knowledge for questions that either appear often or would make good reference questions to link people to.

The two I specifically have in mind are "How do I identify the difference between Nikon DSLR full and cropped frame cameras and lenses?" and "How does crop factor apply to Nikon DSLR full and cropped frame camera and lens combinations?"

On this site, are "Question and Answer" (where the user posts both a question and answer simultaneously) questions like these appropriate/helpful to post, or are they obnoxious and unhelpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Canonical Q&A are fine.

Not sure I understand your 2nd proposed question though. Is it something specific to Nikon?  We already have a lot of general questions covering full/crop sensors with FX/DX lens combinations.

Comment: I am proposing the second question because it is specific to Nikon cameras and lenses and I see a lot of people making an incorrect assumption about Nikon lens crop factors. I'll try to make the question as clear as possible.

Comment: @NoahL I think we _have_ your second question at [Does a Nikon DX lens on a FX camera get subjected to the 1.5X crop factor?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7824/does-a-nikon-dx-lens-on-a-fx-camera-get-subjected-to-the-1-5x-crop-factor), if I'm not misunderstanding what you're saying.

Comment: It was a mistake I made, @mattdm

Comment: @NoahL Which was?

Comment: Crop factor and lens labeling on Nikon DX lenses (I was given incorrect information by a Nikon customer service rep)

Comment: @NoahL .... which _is_ covered by that question, right?

Comment: Yes, the answer is there